# iTunes isRunning with NSTask

Tags: boolean, itunes, nstimer, nstask

So I am trying to make an if based on if iTunes is running or not. I need this because my application gets the track name. This track name has already been accomplished and works but I do not want iTunes always running...

So I decided to try a NSTask with setLaunchPath instance to check if iTunes.app isRunning. The code below is self explanatory but for some reason it keeps hitting my else if when iTunes is open. I call this method in my awakeFromnib by an nstimer every 5 seconds.

```
-(IBAction)ifRunning:(id)pID; {
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes"];
if ([task isRunning]==TRUE) {
    NSLog(@"iTunes is Running, hit if");
    NSString *track = ([self getCurrentTrack]);
    //getCurrentTrack another one of my methods


}

else if ([task isRunning] == FALSE) {
    NSLog(@"iTunes is not running, hit else if");\
    [trackName setTitle:(@"iTunes is Not Playing")];

}

else {
    NSLog(@"Hit else");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using the code below. Hope this post is useful!

```
-(IBAction)ifRunning:(id)pID; {
NSLog(@"Process check ");
NSWorkspace *ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSArray *runningAppDictionaries = [ws launchedApplications];
NSDictionary *aDictionary;

for (aDictionary in runningAppDictionaries)
{
    //  NSLog(@"Open App: %@", [aDictionary valueForKey:@"NSApplicationName"]);

    if ([[aDictionary valueForKey:@"NSApplicationName"] isEqualToString:@"iTunes"])
    {
        NSLog(@"iTunes is Is Running");
        [self getCurrentTrack:nil];
        break;
    }

    else {
        NSLog(@"iTunes is not running.");
    }
} 


}
```